# NGNIX reverse proxy default setup

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, server, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to install node setup on AWS with OS ubuntu 20.04 with nginx web server.
Issue is that when we put the project folder in /var/www/html/project_folder and run the npm start in's given error [nodemon] starting `babel-node src --source-maps`
error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available Public_ Ip:3000
instead already put public ip in /etc/ngix/site available/default file,
.env and index.js. PFA
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Typically, NGINX expects any servers you are proxying to to be reachable at startup, otherwise fails.

```
: address not available 70.54.129.105:3000
```

most likely node isn't reachable - make sure your node app is running, then start nginx.

Also, good idea to not hard-code the node ip:port inside proxy config, but use a variable, makes it easy to reference inside config, e.g my-nginx-app.conf included/imported by nginx.conf :

```
map $host $my_node_server_x {
  default http:\/\/172.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  ...
  location {
    ...
    proxy_pass $my_node_server_x
    # other proxy settings
  }
}
```

[NGINX documentation has Example](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/) config for proxying.